# How can I call an sbt task from Gradle?

Tags: gradle, sbt

How do I call a task on an sbt project from a Gradle build?  I would like to call an existing sbt task, rather than port and duplicate the task's code into my Gradle build.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this without needing to have sbt installed on the machine I'm running from.

As a simple yet concrete example, assume I have the following project structure:

```
parent_directory
  gradle_project
    build.gradle
    [...]
  sbt_project
    build.sbt
    [...]
```

and the following `build.sbt` file:

```
val helloTask = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Print hello")
helloTask := println("Hello world!")
```

I would like to call the "hello" sbt task defined in `build.sbt` from a "helloSbt" Gradle task defined in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) project provides a stand-alone script called [sbt](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt) which can be directly used to run sbt without having it on the machine first.  This can be called via an "Exec" task in the Gradle project, specifying the sbt task to run as a program argument.

First, copy the `sbt` file from [sbt-extras/sbt](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt) into the local project. Assuming the sbt script has been copied into project as `gradle_project/sbt-extras/sbt`, the following Gradle task will execute the "hello" task in `build.sbt`:

```
task helloSbt(type: Exec) {
    workingDir new File(project.projectDir.parentFile, 'sbt_project')
    executable new File(project.projectDir, 'sbt-extras/sbt')
    args 'hello'
}
```